# Require email to download a file

Tags: php

I have developed a require an email to download a file in PHP. But I have a bit of a problem on how to validate the second field email.  Basically, when a user wants to download a file, he/she will require subscribing first using his/her valid email address through a link to his/her email box.  So once the email address has been validated by click on the link an  email will be sent to download a file. I have created one file called subscribe and validation doesn't work for the second email field. So my question is: do I need to create a second subscribe email field?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow it's a bit unclear what you're asking please rephrase your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link to validate the email

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: link only answers are discouraged